# How to run code before (or after) each test in karma

Tags: requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, squirejs

I'm looking to use squire.js with karma and want to do a squire.clean() to clean away all the mocks before the next test suite (I'm using jasmine) is run but I cannot see a way to configure karma to run something before (or after) a test suite.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do this in an afterEach block in Jasmine. Also, making separate instances of Squire.js where appropriate is acceptable.